# adding class to mfc project

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to add a class which holds the object of the gui. The file is COptimataModulDlg, and the new class I want to add is Manager.

I've tried writing this and it didnt work:

```
//Manager.h
#pragma once

class Manager
{
public:

    Manager();
    ~Manager();
private:
         COptimataModulDlg omg;   //the problem is with this line
};
```

it works only when I move this line to manager.cpp and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't #include the file where **COptimataModulDlg** is defined in Manager.h? Maybe it is included in manager.cpp?